# Database design for autoencoder output

Tags: mysql, database, database-design, autoencoder

I have a dataset of images on which I'm running a autoencoder to encode them in a vector of floats of length 32. To store these float values should I create 32 named columns or just put it in a BLOB of text and parse this text when need be? What would be the perf benefits of using the former vs latter?

Example of the data:

```
key:72
value:[1.8609547680625838e-8,2.9573993032272483e-8,0.9999995231628418,0.03153182193636894,
       0.000003173188815708272,0.9999996423721313,0.8707512617111206,0.00005991563375573605,
       0.9999498128890991,0.9999982118606567,0.947956383228302,0.9749470353126526,
       0.9999994039535522,5.490094281412894e-7,0.9999681711196899,0.9958689212799072]
```

I would always be retrieving all the values for given image IDs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tables don't have performance. *Queries* have performance. Any consideration you have to make your database storage give optimal performance, it has to be made in the context of what types of queries you will run against the data.

- If you will always query for the full array of values as a single entity, then use a blob.
- If you will always query for a specific value in the Nth position in the array, then maybe a series of columns is good.
- If you want to do aggregate queries like MIN(), MAX(), AVG() on the data using SQL, then make a second table with one float value per row.

You can't make this decision until you know the queries you will need to run.

Comment: I'll always be running the query for all the values in the array. Is storing the values on a blob and retrieving it then casting it to float slower than just storing the values as floats and running a `select * from`?

Comment: In that case, I doubt there will be any significant difference.

Answer (score 1):

Well usually you would use a `mapping table` to map which values belong to which vector.

But since the `array` you provided is all part of one value, one vector, and because using a `mapping table` would require adding 32 rows to the table for each vector maybe it is best to just save it as `TEXT/BLOB`.